# RxJava 2 - повторная подписка на буфер

Tags: java, rxjava, rxandroid

Есть созданный `Flowable` без оберток:

```
Flowable flowable = Flowable.create(..., BUFFER).subscribeOn(newThread());
```

На него идет подписка (**асинхронная**):

```
flowable.subscribe(...);
```

Через какое-то время

```
Thread.sleep(...);
```

на него идет подписка (**синхронная**):

```
flowable.blockingSubscribe(...);
```

В результате `flowable` выполняется заново. Как сделать так, чтобы во второй раз приходили значения из уже посчитанного буфера и ожидалось окончание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось довольно простым.

```
Flowable.create(..., BUFFER).subscribeOn(newThread()).replay().autoConnect();
```

Тогда каждый подписчик будет получать общие результаты и дожидаться конца выполнения.